# Django LogoutView redirect to previous page

Tags: python, django

I am using Django's `auth.LogoutView` class in my urls.py. I can redirect the user to a specific page using `LogoutView.as_view(next_page='main:index')` after logout. If I left out the `next_page` part, it redirects to a Django admin interface with a thank you message and a option to login again, which is the admin login page. I want to redirect the user to the page they were on before clicking the logout url on the navbar.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
next_page = request.get_full_path()
```

Comment: Please understand the question first and only answer if you know it correct.

Answer (score -2):

in your seettings.py file, add

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

your logout views :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from yourprojectName import settings

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect(settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL)
```

Comment: It will redirect to the main page, I want to redirect to the page from where the user clicked logout.